# How to move/remove the bracing from this desk?

Tags: furniture, metal

So, I am the proud new owner of [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003FSTNBQ) new desk!  I've never needed a desk before.  Unfortunately, along the *long* side, I find myself leaning and writing.  A lot.  The brace at the bottom really gets in  the way of my legs, sadly.

I have a lot of homework.

So, does anyone know a good way to say, move the brace up on the desk so my feet are free?  I'll buy a sheet of hard clear plastic and epoxy it on there if I have to.  And yes, I understand the equation *t=r X F*... I know why it has to be braced.

It would nice if I could avoid any permanent damage to the desk!

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the brace, drill holes into the other bars that are thiner and move the brace up closer to the glass. Obviously the closer you get to the top the less steady it will become so only allow enough room to where you are comfortable. I actually use to have the same desk in black. The glass makes it heavy so as long as one side is braced correctly it shouldn't move to much.